# ListView is not scrolling smoothly and fastly when downloading images in background

Tags: listview

I have one `ListView` and I am downloading images in Background for every 5 images the `ListView` should refresh, and above this list I have `HorizontalScrollView` which has some customized `TextView`s.

When I click on one `TextView` that one category, it should display it's corresponding `ListView`. When I switch from one to another category it is taking a long time.

Some times I am getting the Dialog, as though the application is not responding ForceClose or wait.

Can anybody tell me why these are all taking place in my application.

Comment: It'd help to know which framework you are using. Is that Common Controls, MVC, ...?

Answer (score 0):

My crystal ball tells me that you are fetching data synchronously in the GUI thread. Don't do that.

You can either start a separate thread performing the downloads and updating the listview as images arrive, or (if you have a networking framework that supports that) use asynchronous I/O to get the images (and update the listview when images arrive).

In either case, you need to display a placeholder while the image is loading.